# Android using Picasso and TextDrawable in ListView

Tags: android, picasso

I have a `ListView` of user images. Some users have a profile picture and I use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load the images. 
If user doesn't have an image, using [TextDrawable](https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable) I set his image in my listview adapter as shown below.

```
if (picture!=null) {
         Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(picture);
         Picasso.with(holder.pic.getContext()).load(imageUri.toString()).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.pic);

} else {
        ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL; // or use DEFAULT
        int color = generator.getColor(userName);
        String userChar = userName.substring(0, 1);
        TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
                .buildRound(userChar.toUpperCase(), color);
        holder.pic.setImageDrawable(drawable);

    }
```

Problem is when I scroll the list, sometimes the images mess up and those who don't have an image and are supposed to be displayed with `TextDrawable` are displayed with another users profile picture. 
If I use Picasso to load all images this doesnt happen. Is there anyway to pass a TextDrawable object into picasso to solve this problem? Or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `TextDrawable` as drawable placeholder for Picasso. Then I think your problem would be resolved.

```
ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL; // or use DEFAULT
int color = generator.getColor(userName);
String userChar = userName.substring(0, 1);
TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
            .buildRound(userChar.toUpperCase(), color);
Picasso.with(holder.pic.getContext()).
    load(imageUri.toString()).
    placeholder(drawable).
    error(drawable).
    centerCrop().
    into(holder.pic);
```